# Swift3 Alamofire SwiftyJSON get data outside founcion

Tags: ios, alamofire, xcode8, swifty-json

I was trying to get swfityjson and almo to work in Xcode 8 
like in the post in this page:

[Showing JSON data on TableView using SwiftyJSON and Alamofire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36019725/showing-json-data-on-tableview-using-swiftyjson-and-alamofire/39738146#39738146)

But I can not get the data from the self.
This helped me a little, but I am stuck with the count. Someone please help me with this, beacuse I am new to swift and have spent the day trying to understand how to get the count of rows and the data out of the almo function.

```
 import UIKit
 import Alamofire
 import SwiftyJSON

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

var names = [String]()
var rowCount = [Int]()
var tableTitle = [String]()
typealias JSONStandard = [String : AnyObject]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}


func callAlamo(){
    let url = "http://xxxxxx/xxxx/xxxxxx.php"
    //let id = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "UserDefaults")
    Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON{(respones)->Void in

        if let value = respones.result.value{
            let json = JSON(value)
            let rows = json["items"].arrayValue
            for anItem in rows {
                let title: String? = anItem["SupplierName"].stringValue
                self.tableTitle.append(title!)
                 //print(self.tableTitle.count)
            }

        }


    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    // let  isUserLoggedin = UserDefaults.standard.boll(forKey: "userLogIn")
    let ststus = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "userLogIn")
    if  ststus == "false" {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginView", sender: self)
    }else{

        callAlamo()
    }
}



@IBAction func logout(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "userLogIn")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginView", sender: self)
}


  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print (tableTitle)
    return self.tableTitle.count
}
```

}

I am unable to get the tableTitle.count. Thanks!

Comment: Reload the tableview after got the response

Answer (score 0):

UITableView Delegate methods are called before viewDidAppear. So you need to reload the UITableView after got the response from server

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()             
        }
```

After the for loop.

Comment: Thanks i did add to the end of the loop and there is no change

Comment: This does not work get a error in Xcode. "Expected declaration"

Answer (score -1):

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

var names = [String]()
var rowCount = [Int]()
var tableTitle = [String]()
typealias JSONStandard = [String : AnyObject]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}


func callAlamo(){
    let url = "http://pos1.dermedia.co.il/iphone/getLasttransactions.php?cardid="
    //let id = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "UserDefaults")
    Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON{(respones)->Void in

        if let value = respones.result.value{
            let json = JSON(value)
            //   print (json["items"].arrayValue)
            let rows = json["items"].arrayValue
           // print (rows)
            for anItem in rows {
                let title: String? = anItem["SupplierName"].stringValue
                self.tableTitle.append(title!)
                 print(self.tableTitle.count)
            }

        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    // let  isUserLoggedin = UserDefaults.standard.boll(forKey: "userLogIn")
    let ststus = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "userLogIn")
    if  ststus == "false" {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginView", sender: self)
    }else{

        callAlamo()
        print ("gggggg")
        print(self.tableTitle.count)
    }
}



   @IBAction func logout(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "userLogIn")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginView", sender: self)

}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print (self.tableTitle)
    print("hhh")
    return tableTitle.count
}





}
```

Comment: The same I have answered

Comment: Ragul thanks for the help. but in func tableView i do not get the count it is still "0"